# Yii2 Advanced раздиление шаблона

Tags: yii2

Я использую Yii2 Adnvanced. Написал такой .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# Если запрос начинается с /admin, то заменяем на /backend/web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteRule ^admin\/?(.*) /backend/web/$1

# Добавляем другой запрос /frontend/web/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend/web|backend/web|admin)
RewriteRule (.*) /frontend/web/$1

# Если frontend запрос
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/frontend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /frontend/web/index.php

# Если backend запрос
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/backend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /backend/web/index.php
```

Сайт по адресу http://site.ru грузится хорошо, а вот админка по адресу http://site.ru/admin сначала подгружает код админки, а ниже еще основной сайт. 
Заметил, что если убрать

```
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>
<?php $this->endBody() ?>
```

ошибка пропадает. Помогите, уже не знаю, куда смотреть

Answer (score 0):

В корне сайта такой `.htaccess`:

```
Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore */*
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^admin$ backend/web/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin)
RewriteRule ^admin(\/?.*)$ backend/web/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/
RewriteRule ^(\/?.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L]
```

В `frontend/web` и `backend/web`:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: так же, в /admin грузит еще и frontend

Comment: Очень интересно. В шаблоне может где-то идёт подключение фронтендовских вьюшек?

Comment: проверил, не нашел